# PHP - remove repeated elements from string (<hr>)

Tags: php, function, post

I have a string that shows each post then a `<hr>` element at the end of a post. But I have it so if you delete a post it shows leaves the `<hr>` element there so I need a script that will detect if there is more than one `<hr>` element and narrow it down so that it will only be left with one below each post.

Is there any chance that it is possible to do???

here is what it looks like to me:

```
post text post text post text post text post text 
<hr>
post text post text post text post text post text post text 
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
post text post text post text 
<hr>
<hr>
post text post text post text post text 
<hr>
```

And I need it to be like:

```
post text post text post text post text post text 
<hr>
post text post text post text post text post text post text 
<hr>
post text post text post text 
<hr>
post text post text post text post text
```

Comment: Some PHP code of what you have tried so far would be helpful - not only to see where the problem is, but also to understand your question: How do you "delete" posts? How do you render them? Where do you get them from?

Comment: Delete the `<hr>` when you delete the post?

Comment: Consider accepting an answer if it answers your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- i'm using an explode `<hr>` here
- then filtering out the empty elements
- and then simply re-imploding with `<hr>`
- probably more expensive then a `preg_replace()`

PHP:

```
<?php

$content = <<<STR
post text post text post text post text post textA
<hr>
post text post text post text post text post text post textB
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
post text post text post textC
<hr>
<hr>
post text post text post text post textD
STR;

function remove_duplicate_hr_tags($string)
{
    $lines             = explode('<hr>', $string);
    $trimmedArray      = array_map('trim', $lines);
    $emptyRemovedArray = array_filter($trimmedArray);
    $content           = implode("\n<hr>\n", $emptyRemovedArray);

    return $content;
}

echo remove_duplicate_hr_tags($content);
```

Output

```
post text post text post text post text post textA
<hr>
post text post text post text post text post text post textB
<hr>
post text post text post textC
<hr>
post text post text post text post textD
```

Comment: more expensive but more intuitive (than my answer) !

Comment: RegExp one-liners are powerful, but always a bit complicated :) and there are so many ways to do things...

Answer (score 2):

Test this regex:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(<hr>[\n\r\s]{0,}<hr>[\n\r\s]{0,}){1,}/', '<hr>', $str);
echo $str;
```

See this live running code : https://eval.in/521981

Answer (score 0):

could have been more helpful if you provide code.

my suggestion would be group them in div .

```
<div class="container">
     <p>post 1 text</p>
     <hr>
</div>
<div class="container">
     <p>post 2 text</p>
     <hr>
</div>
```